# Restart fermentation stuck at 1.026SG?

Tags: wine, yeast

I have a berry wine, stuck at 1.026SG and with a high malic acid (quite sour).  Should I try to restart the fermentation by adding fresh yeast?  What about yeast from another vat?  Is there enough sugar still in the vat to continue the ferment?

Answer (score 1):

There are specific steps to restarting a stuck wine/mead/high gravity beer. You can read the whole procedure [here](http://blog.eckraus.com/making-a-wine-yeast-starter-to-restart-a-stuck-fermentation). You'll need some champagne yeast or some other special yeast used to restart stuck fermentations. But it starts with this:

> For restarting 5 or 6 gallons, take a quart jar and fill it half way
>   with the wine in question. Add to that, water until the jar is 2/3
>   full. Put in the mix a 1/4 teaspoon of yeast nutrient, and 3
>   tablespoons of sugar. Be sure that the sugar becomes completely
>   dissolve. Now you can add a whole packet of the Champagne yeast. Cover
>   the jar with a paper towel and secure with a rubber band.